# Biometrics x990 connection via TCP/IP

Tags: python, tcp, biometrics

I'm trying to connect a biometric device. **Device Make: eSSL and Device Model: x990**. I'm not a programmer to make this sample code to work. Please help me to connect to the device via TCP/IP and fetch the data. The sample code as follows: [Python Code]

```
params = protocol=TCP,ipaddress=192.168.12.154,port=4370,timeout=4000,passwd=”
self.commpro = windll.LoadLibrary("plcommpro.dll")      
constr = create_string_buffer(params)
self.hcommpro = self.commpro.Connect(constr)
```

I registered (*.dll). My working Environment is Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). I got this code from Google Search.

Comment: You're trying to load a DLL in Ubuntu?

Comment: Actually I'm trying in run the code in Windows during testing. My production environment is Ubuntu where I should Implement this code.

Comment: Well, unless you've done some low-level hacky stuff, you most likely won't be able to load a DLL in Ubuntu.

Comment: MD XF, thanks for pointing. Do you have any idea on biometric. I need to connect to the device and fetch the data. I'm not aware of programing actually. If you can please help me out.

Comment: @ChaitanyaHusys, please check http://essl.co.in/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html, if helps you

Comment: @Ravanan, https://essl.co.in/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html link does not work, please update the link

Answer (score 0):

ZkTeco devices are launched only with windows SDK. Your code would work only in windows platform. You mentioned, that your production environment is Ubuntu. I assume that, your application is going to run in a server whereas the device is connected to your at local environment. If so, technically, this is not possible. You have to go for the HTTP communication. Check http://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html if it helps for http communication